# Export array to be used in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

In my post request, I want to check if `thisString` exists in another javascript file array.

Array.js

```
exports.names = [
    'John',
    'Mary'
]
```

Main.js

```
if (names.includes(thisString)) {
    ...do stuff...
}
```

if `thisString = Mary`, `Main.js` returns "undefined". If I `console.log(names)` it returns the array. But `console.log(names[0])` is undefined. And If I copy and paste the array into the `Main.js` file it works as intended.

I want to have the array in another file just to clean things up a bit. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you import `names` in Main.js?

Comment: What are your import/export statements?

Comment: `const names = require('../array');`

Comment: @John107 Is Array.js in a folder above Main.js ?

Comment: @Leo Yes.... is that a problem? I want to access it from multiple files.

Comment: @John107 No, not a problem, just checking the relative path of the import points to the right file. In your comment you wrote `require('../array');`, yet in the question you wrote `Array.js`, is that a typo ?

Answer (score 34):

Typescript :

Array.ts

```
export let array = [1,2,3];
```

Main.ts

```
import {array} from "./Array.ts"
array.map(item => console.log(item +1))
```

Javascript (nodejs)

array.js

```
exports.array =  [1,2,3];
```

main.js

```
let module = require('./array.js');

let array = module.array;

array.map(item => console.log(item +1))
```

Answer (score 4):

The below works for me. You could also try:

### **Array.js**

```
exports.names = [
    'John',
    'Mary'
]
```

### **Main.js**

```
const data = require('./array.js');

const thisString = 'Mary';
if (data && data.names && data.names.includes(thisString)) {
    console.log('You are in!');
}
```

Comment: this 'should' work, but returns `undefined` in my application. I am unsure why.

Comment: Strange! In my solution I am assuming your `array.js` and `main.js` are in same folder, otherwise you need to modify the import path.

Comment: Yes it's very strange! I have the correct path for the `array.js` so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for me is to export like so:

array.js

```
export const names = [
  'john',
  'James',
  'Jeff'
];
```

in main.js
Import variable as a named-import

```
import { names} from './array.js'
console.log(names)
```

//Output => ['john', 'James', 'Jeff']

With this method you can import multiple variables from a file as long as you export them.
However if you're exporting multiple variable from the same file its best to follow this convention:

```
export { x, y, z };
const x = 1;
const y = ['a', 'b'];
const z = {"name": "James",};
```